# STL binary_search()

Tags: c++11, stl, binary-search

I created a struct directory with data members as string name and address and phone no.s. I want to perform binary search using STL c++ binary_search() to display info by taking input as name. And my structure is array of structs. I have successfully sorted the structure by name. How do I search and display? I am not getting the syntax.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<vector>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct directory
    {
        string name;
        char address[50];
        long long int ph; 
        int pin;
    }d[10];
    bool compare(directory & lhs, directory & rhs)
    {
        if(lhs.name!=rhs.name)
        {
            return lhs.name < rhs.name;
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter name: ";
            cin>>d[i].name;
            cout<<"\nEnter Address:";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(d[i].address,50);
            cout<<"\nEnter ph. no.: ";
            cin>>d[i].ph;
        }
        sort(d,d+10,&compare);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<"\nName: "<<d[i].name;
            cout<<"\nAddress:"<<d[i].address;
            cout<<"\nPh. no.: "<<d[i].ph<<"\n";
        }
        string nam;
        cout<<"Enter the first name to search: ";
        cin>>nam;
        if(binary_search(d,d+10,nam,&compare));
        {
            cout<<d->name<<"\n";
            cout<<d->address<<"\n";
            cout<<d->ph<<"\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `std::binary_search` only tells you whether the element is in the collection or not. You need `std::lower_bound` to actually locate the element in the collection.

Comment: Your `compare` function is wrong - it may run off the closing brace without ever hitting `return` statement, thereby exhibiting undefined behavior. Also, for the way you are trying to use `std::binary_search` or `std::lower_bound`, you need an asymmetrical comparator that takes `directory` on the left and `std::string` on the right.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have a doubt in syntax. Please help me with the syntax in this part                                                                                                               
         `string nam;
        cout<<"Enter the first name to search: ";
        cin>>nam;
        if(binary_search(d,d+10,nam,&compare));
        {
            cout<<d->name<<"\n";
            cout<<d->address<<"\n";
            cout<<d->ph<<"\n";
        }`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sort function works right when `&compare` argument is passed. The problem is with binary_search arguments. I don't know how to pass arguments to that so that the name is searched and whole record is displayed

Comment: Again - `std::binary_search` is of no help here, you need `std::lower_bound`. [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) comes with an example. You'd need another overload of `compare`, one that can compare a `directory` and a `string`. As to your current `compare` working - if it does, it's only by accident. Drop the `if` check, just make it `return lhs.name < rhs.name;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, it doesn't work when the if statement is dropped. But I don't seem to know how to use `std::lower_bound` in the code even after reading the documentation. What changes should I make in the code to use `std::binary_search` ? Help me with the code please.

Comment: *"Help me with the code please*" [I'm sorry, Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARJ8cAGm6JE) Show what you've tried, explain how it's not working.